# How to get result from different row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, select

Say if I have a table with following data:

```
    ID        Date
----------------------
     2      2017/3/15
     3      2017/6/20
     5      2017/7/8
     6      2018/1/3
     7      2018/1/8
    10      2018/2/20
    11      2018/3/20
    12      2018/4/1
```

Is it possible to make a `select` command to put the date from **previous row** into the current row?

With the result:

```
    ID        Date        PreDate
-------------------------------------
     2      2017/3/15      NULL
     3      2017/6/20    2017/3/15
     5      2017/7/8     2017/6/20
     6      2018/1/3     2017/7/8
     7      2018/1/8     2018/1/3
    10      2018/2/20    2018/1/8
    11      2018/3/20    2018/2/20
    12      2018/4/1     2018/3/20
```

Comment: Read up LAG function.

Comment: Will do! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention which version you are using.

If on 2012+, you can use the `LAG()` function which does exactly what you need. The first parameter is the column to show, the second is how many rows back you will fetch the data from and the third is the value that will be informed if there is no previous row. The `OVER` will determine how the rows are ordered.

```
SELECT
    T.ID,
    T.Date,
    PreviousDate = LAG(T.Date, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY T.Date ASC)
FROM
    YourTable AS T
```

If on 2008+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function. In this case we generate an integer ascending row number and join the result set with the previous row by decreasing the row number by 1.

```
;WITH RowNumering AS
(
    SELECT
        T.ID,
        T.Date,
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.Date ASC)
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
)
SELECT
    T1.ID,
    T1.Date,
    PreviousDate = T2.Date
FROM
    RowNumering AS T1
    LEFT JOIN RowNumering T2 ON T1.RowNumber - 1 = T2.RowNumber
```

These are both called "window functions", it would be great if you take a while to learn how to fully use them :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use row number and join to its own table to do this, something like

```
SELECT ID, Date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RowOrder, 
INTO #tempTable
FROM MyTable

SELECT a.ID, a.Date as Date, b.Date as PreDate
FROM #tempTable a
LEFT JOIN #tempTable b ON b.RowOrder = a.RowOrder - 1
```

Comment: by assumption that the previous row to be taken for the predate column is based on the order of ID colum